# Clustering points using QGIS expressions or virtual layers

Tags: qgis, clustering, virtual-layer, qgis-expression

Is there any way of clustering points using QGIS expressions or virtual layers?

I need a dynamic solution so I cannot use tools that create static layers and as a requirement I cannot use python.
Point cluster symbology is not an option either because I need to have control over labels for clusters.

I've tried the 'easy' way creating buffers in a virtual layer (creating buffers around points, dissolving overlapping buffers and symbolizing buffer centroids with the number of points inside each dissolved buffer) but the result is not as good as I expected despite trying with different buffer distances. Bigger distances group too many points together and smaller distances still group too many points in some areas but do not group many other points that look too close at my working scale and I expected to be grouped.

With Point cluster symbology I get this:
[image: Point cluster symbology]
And with my buffer approach I get this (with the buffer distance I found to give 'best' results):
[image: Centroids of dissolved buffers]

For more details this is the code for the virtual layers (the point layer is called 'Point_elem'):

- Dissolved buffers ('Point_elem_Buffer' layer)

```
WITH RECURSIVE parts AS (
  SELECT t.total, 1 AS ref_id
  FROM totals AS t
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.total, ref_id + 1 AS ref_id
  FROM totals AS t 
  INNER JOIN parts AS p ON p.ref_id < t.total
  ),

totals AS (
  SELECT NumGeometries(geom) AS total
  FROM merged_buff
  ),

merged_buff AS (
  SELECT ST_Union(ST_Buffer(geometry, 11.5)) AS geom
  FROM "Point_elem"
  )

SELECT p.ref_id, GeometryN( m.geom, p.ref_id) as geom
FROM parts AS p
INNER JOIN merged_buff AS m;
```

- Centroids with point count and other stuff for labeling  ('Point_elem_Buffer_Centroids' layer)

```
SELECT ST_CENTROID(buff.geometry), 
buff.ref_id,
GROUP_CONCAT(ext.elem_code) as codes,
count(*) as elem_count
FROM "Point_elem_Buffer" as buff,
"Point_elem" as ext
WHERE ST_Within(ext.geometry, buff.geometry)
GROUP BY buff.ref_id;
```

Comment: It's unclear exactly which rules should be used to cluster. What is "best". If you have PostGIS you can create a view which use some of PostGIS:s algorithms, for example [dbscan](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterDBSCAN.html)

Comment: The data is in a geopackage. Here "best" is grouping that will reduce the number of points so that there are no point overlaps nor too close points nor groups with too many points (5-6 at the most) at my working scale (1:12000).